# How do you tile a window in Awesome Window Manager?

Tags: awesome, tiling-wm

I'm apparently missing some knowledge that is very fundamental about [Awesome Window Manager](https://awesomewm.org/).

I'm using the default configuration that comes with Debian 11 and for the past two weeks I've been using the default floating layout.

Now, I'm ready to venture into utilizing its tiling features, but toggling the top-left layout button has no affect on the layout of my windows. Even when I close all windows, and launch them from scratch, they do not launch into tiles no matter what layout I choose (beforehand) via that layout-toggler-button.

I've watched videos of other people doing this, but (for me) the windows never tile. What I'm I missing here?

Comment: It turns out, that since my applications were launching `Maximized`, Awesome wouldn't tile them. So, in order to experience tiling, all participating windows must not be maximized.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem, even the tile mode was the only avalible in my rc.lua file. The solution is to add a propertie `minimized = true` in the rc.lua file.

For other modifications to how windows are created in awesomewm see https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/awful.spawn.html

Comment: Where, in the rc.lua file, do you add `minimized = true'?